# How to get all checkedboxes in a manual POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

A bit of background, I mainly work in .Net/C# and never did any PHP my whole life and my company gave me an existing PHP code and asked me add some feature to it.

The webpage I need to work on is a catering system. The page recalculates the total price when there are changes to the number of pax. This worked fine if every item in the menu is similarly priced.

```
function RefreshPrice() {
        menuid = getQueryString('menuid');
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                refreshprice: "refreshprice",
                menuid: menuid,

            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    }
```

But now there are items that cost more than others, so I need to recalculate on each item selection. I'm trying to use a hidden field to store the additional price for the item.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="validate-checkbox" item-name="<?php echo $item["Name"];?>"
                                  name="menuitem[]" value="<?php echo $item["Id"];?>">
<input type="hidden" class="addprice" name="addprice" value="<?php echo $item["AddPrice"];?>">
```

But how do I get the values of the hidden field of each selected item so I can do something like this.

```
function RefreshPrice() {
        menuid = getQueryString('menuid');
        addprice= document.getElementsByClassName("addprice:checked").val(); //OR $(".addprice:checked").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                refreshprice: "refreshprice",
                menuid: menuid,
                addprice: addprice,
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    }
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but most answer I found were using form submit POST method and got them using `$_POST["addprice"]`, but this is manually constructing the ajax POST.

Comment: The data will be in $_POST["addprice"] on the server side. That's fine. But the main issue I think is that the Javascript code will only collect the price from _one_ of the hidden fields. Or actually, none of them because `addprice:checked` makes no sense, because hidden fields can't be checked, and because it's not a valid class selector anyway. Your lack of PHP knowledge is not relevant here, the problem seems to be use of javascript/jQuery and selectors.

Comment: I suggest you replace the entire hidden field with a data~ atribute eg `data-price="$item['AddPrice']"` within the checkbox input and then define the id of the checkbox `id="menuitem[]"` so in the end you can just define the addvalue variable like this `$(#menuitem).data('price');`, I can try to write the code for you think you can sort it out this way, I am used to writing ajax code, hope you don't mind it

Comment: @ADyson I tried ```$(".addprice").val();``` but yes it is as you said, that only collect the first field in the form. So I'm trying to convey what I want on that line, maybe I should use a pseudo code to highlight that I don't have a working code for collecting ```addprice``` field.

Comment: you need to loop through all the checked checkboxes, find the related hidden field for each checked box, and put the ID and the price together into an object, and add those to an array, and then submit that to the the server. (Because if you don't submit the ID as well,how is the server going to know which price relates to which item?). Better to send this all as JSON I would think. Either that or just `.serialize()` the whole form and let jQuery handle sending the data in a sensible format. Then on the server side you can `var_dump($_POST);` to debug the structure you receive.

Comment: But...what are these hidden fields? Are they values which are being updated by the user when they edit this form, or are they values which actually are already stored in the database and don't get modified? Because if they don't get modified, there's no point in having them in hidden fields to be submitted again, it just leaves them vulnerable to a malicious user modifying them. If that's the case, then just submit the IDs of the checked boxes, and forget about the hidden fields..

Comment: @ADyson Yes, these fields will not be modified by the user. I will change my method of handling this recalculation. I will use your suggestion and collect the id of checked items and handle the additional price server side. Thanks

Comment: @ksp Please check my updated answer, it provides a solution of identifying the selected checkboxes and passing them on to the server through AJAX from where you can do whatever you want with them

Answer (score 0):

I think its not a good idea to store values in hidden form fields. because for security reasons user can modify your old values.

my suggestion is, you should send form value to your PHP and make a DB call and compare the values again. if you found the changes then update value otherwise leave it.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and lots of testing I found a way to achieve what you desire so here is an example of it...

I've been testing this example on an app that I am building so the example will not be using your code, but the method is the same, you will just need to adjust it to work with your code...

Okay so first let's create the needed table and populate it with few rows

**PHP**

```
// Establish Connection (change the connection details if necessary)
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost','root','','test');

// Create table
mysqli_query($mysqli, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS permissions(
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)");

// Populate table
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO permissions (
    name,
    description
    ) VALUES (
        'manage_users', 
        'Can add/edit users'
        ),
        ('permission_plus',
        'Can manage roles/permissions & access logs'
        )");
    ?>
```

So, in this example I will be trying to create a new role for my web office and assign the role some of the existing permissions and to achieve that we will need to create a form that will display all of the existing roles from the table that we have just created...

**HTML**

```
<!--Make sure to include JQuery CDN-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="addRole">
    <form method="POST" id="addroles">
        <input type="text" id="rolename" placeholder="Role Name" />
        <input type="text" id="role_description" placeholder="Role Description" />
        <hr /><span class="title">Include Permissions</span>
        <div id="checks">
            <?php
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM permissions");
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $permid = $row['id'];
                $permname = $row['name'];
                $permdesc = $row['description'];
                echo "<label class='checks' title='$permdesc'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='selected' data-id='$permid'/>
                 $permname</label>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Role" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, after we have the form displaying all the rows from the "permissions" table in a form of a checkbox, we can finally come to the most important part of the code, which is storing the selected checkboxes in an array using JavaScript/JQuery and passing them on to the server using AJAX...

**JavaScript**

```
$('#addroles').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let rolename = $('#rolename').val();
    let roledesc = $('#role_description').val();
    let permissions = [];

    $('.selected').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            permissions.push($(this).data('id'));
        }
    });

    if(rolename != '' && roledesc != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addrole.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                rolename: rolename,
                roledesc: roledesc,
                permissions: permissions
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, the script here says, after you submit the form, first prevent it from it's default function and assign the values from the form fields to this specific variables, and when it comes to the checkboxes, create an array and then for each checked checkbox - push the value stored in data-id inside the previously created array, then fire AJAX and pass on all the variables to the server and after the server handles the data, please tell us what it said

**addrole.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost','root','','test');

$permissions = $_POST['permissions'];
foreach($permissions as $permission){
    echo $permission.' ';
}
```

The server breaks down the passed array of selected checkboxes using a `foreach` function and echoes the value stored in the data-id of each selected checkbox and we can see the result of it in our browser's console.

Here is some CSS for the sake of the appearance of this example

**CSS**

```
#addRole{
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    position: relative;
    width:30%;
    padding:20px;
}
#addRole input[type='text']{
    width:80%;
    height:40px;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 0px;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    outline:none;
}#addRole input[type='submit']{
    width:80%;
    height:40px;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 0px;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    outline:none;
}
#addRole form hr{
    width:30%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.checks{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    text-indent: -20px;
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    border:1px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);
    margin: auto;
}
#checks{
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    margin:10px;
    display: flex-box;
    text-align: center;
}
#addRole input[type='checkbox']{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;
    outline:none;
    text-align: center;
}
.title{
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This **still** won't work. Seriously, test your code instead of guessing.

Comment: now you've removed the AJAX part entirely, which was the whole point of the question!

Comment: Done. It's not directly relevant to the answer but as a general point: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so if you have undetected security bugs in your code
this leaves your DB open to hackers.
Create a separate user account specifically for this app which has only the permissions it _needs_ in order to work.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the info, I never thought of the importance of the user you're using to connect to the db

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you've realized it is a security issue to calculate prices from data that can be altered on the client-side. Also, if the server-side is simply there to add the values, why not handle it directly in the javascript.
either way, the code below should collect data values of the checked items.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="validate-checkbox priceItems" item-name="<?php echo $item['Name'];?>" name="menuitem[]" value="<?php echo $item['Id'];?>" data-price="<?php echo $item['AddPrice'];?>">
```

you can add prices as a parameter to the data of the ajax function or do the sum here.

```
var prices = $('.priceItems:checked').map(function() { 
                return $(this).data('price'); 
            }).get();
```